# Django Template Cache? Templates which don't exist are renderd

Tags: python, django, django-templates

Usually I have the opposite problem, Django can't find the templates.

Lastly, I change a template of mine called `custmber_view.html`, but Django didn't notice the chagnes. 
I tried flushing all caches, without success. In my dispair, I completely removed the template
hoping to see the familiar `TemplateDoesNotExist` exception. 
To my surprise, Django keeps rendering the template! Although it is not found on the hard-drive.
Can someone suggest a solution to this mystery?

Comment: Could you include some relevant code? Do you know it's that template and not a similar template?

Comment: I'm not aware of any template cache. Have you tried restarting the webserver?

Comment: @AG, I tried, it didn't help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ARGH, legacy projects, I am doomed to fix them for ever. Somewise guy put the following in  `settings.py`:

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(project_dir, u'templates'),
    u'/var/www/venv2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/backoffice/templates',
)
```

I feel [like this now ...](https://31.media.tumblr.com/c41f651322defdb78ab09b1fd86d310c/tumblr_inline_n0e0qcRAIK1raprkq.gif)

So, conclusion, If you are working on a project which was not made as a Django App, always make sure you read the variable `TEMPLATE_DIRS`. 
But for your colleagues future (and for better moral) always follow [How to write reusable Django app](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/reusable-apps/)